# Delegate methods not called if implementing class is marked private?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, private

Here's a short snippet of Swift code that works fine (where "fine" is defined as "Parsing!" being printed a whole bunch in response to calling the class method `Parse.parse`):

```
import Foundation

class Parse {
  class func parse(stream: NSInputStream) {
    return Parser().parse(stream)
  }

  class Parser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    func parse(stream: NSInputStream) {
      let XMLParser = NSXMLParser(stream: stream)
      let delegate = XMLParserDelegate()
      XMLParser.delegate = delegate
      XMLParser.parse()
    }

    class XMLParserDelegate: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
      func parser(
        parser: NSXMLParser,
        didStartElement elementName: String,
        namespaceURI: String?,
        qualifiedName qName: String?,
        attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
      {
        NSLog("Parsing!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes when I attempt to use Swift's visibility features. In particular, I do not want to make the `Parser` class visible to other files (because there is no reason for it to be visible). If I declare it via `private class Parser …` however, the code ceases to work! `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` is no longer called!

This all seems bizarre to me and unlike how it would work in any other language. As such, I feel like one of the following two things must be true:

1. Swift's system for namespacing is, at best, weird. More plainly, it just seems broken to me.
2. Swift is fine and I am just doing something very silly! If that's the case, then great! Please let me know what it is!

Thanks for the help, everyone!

---

**Edit:** Here's a slightly trimmed-down version. As before, the code works fine until the `Parser` class is marked `private`:

```
import Foundation

class Parse {
  class func parse(stream: NSInputStream) {
    return Parser().parse(stream)
  }
}

class Parser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
  func parse(stream: NSInputStream) {
    let XMLParser = NSXMLParser(stream: stream)
    XMLParser.delegate = self
    XMLParser.parse()
  }

  func parser(
    parser: NSXMLParser,
    didStartElement elementName: String,
    namespaceURI: String?,
    qualifiedName qName: String?,
    attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
  {
    NSLog("Parsing!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I have copied your code into a test project, marked both Parser and XMLParserDelegate as private, and it still worked correctly.

Comment: @MartinR Strange. Are you using Swift 1.2 like I am?

Comment: No, that was Swift 1.1. But with Swift 1.2 I *can* reproduce it, by marking Parser or XMLParserDelegate or the didStartElement  method as private.

Comment: @MartinR Wonderful! This seems like a bug that was introduced in Swift 1.2 then. Thank you! I'll keep an eye on this question for a bit to see if anyone else chimes in with something relevant and then package this up as a bug report for Apple.

Comment: can confirm this behaviour on Swift 1.2 Xcode 6.3 beta 3 (6D543q) using MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the investigation done by MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487142/delegate-methods-not-called-if-implementing-class-is-marked-private/28488444#comment45296955_28487142), this appears to be a bug (or something like it) that was introduced in Swift 1.2. Presumably this behavior is not intentional as I'm unaware of any other (reasonable, statically typed) language where marking a class as private can silently break your code at runtime. I'll follow up with Apple and see what they think of all this!

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be surprising. `NSXMLParserDelegate` includes the following:

```
optional func parser(_ parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI namespaceURI: String, qualifiedName qualifiedName: String, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Since it's optional, there must somewhere in `NSXMLParser` be a `doesRespondToSelector()` call. It shouldn't be surprising that function would fail if the underlying class is private. (Given its interaction with dynamic ObjC calls, it wouldn't be shocking if it worked, either; but neither approach should be considered broken, and what you describe better matches what you asked for; which is that these methods be private.)

The right answer here is that `XMLParserDelegate` needs to be public along with its implementation of `NSXMLParserDelegate`. `Parser` doesn't have to be public, and any non-protocol methods don't need to be public. But `NSXMLParser` needs to be able to see its delegate methods if you want it to call them.

What's a bit more surprising is that this isn't a compiler error.

---

EDIT: <strike>While it still surprises me that this doesn't create a compiler error (and I feel *that* is probably a bug),</strike> the key finding is that `private` means private. It means that other files cannot see the method, and so `respondsToSelector()` will fail. To demonstrate this in a simpler form:

#### main.swift

```
import Foundation
private class Impl : NSObject, P {
    func run() {
        println("Running")
    }
}
let c = Container(p: Impl())
c.go()
```

#### more.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc internal protocol P: NSObjectProtocol {
    optional func run()
}

// Change internal to private to see change
internal struct Container {
    let p: P
    func go() {
        println(p.dynamicType) // Impl for internal, (Impl in ...) for private
        if p.respondsToSelector(Selector("run")) {
            p.run!() // if run is internal or public
        } else {
            println("Didn't implement") // if run is private
        }

        // Or the Swiftier way:
        if let run = p.run {
            run() // if run is internal or public
        } else {
            println("Didn't implement") // if run is private
        }
    }
}
```

To see a little more of the details on why this is true, we can look at `p.dynamicType`. If `p` is internal, then we see that its type is `Impl`. If it is private, we see its type is `(Impl in _9F9099C659B8A128A78BAA9A7C0E0368)`. Making things `private` makes their type and internal structure private.

Private just hides much more than internal. It impacts the runtime, not just the compile time.

And the more I think about it, the more I see why it can't give us a compiler error. It is legal to implement an internal protocol with a private class. The place it goes sideways is when we pass it as a parameter to another access area and then try to introspect it dynamically. And the answer is "don't do that."

It is possible that will change in the future. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/1073092#1073092. It's worth bringing up as a bugreport, but I still wouldn't assume it's a bug; it could certainly be intended behavior.

Comment: This explanation doesn't quite make sense to me.

The thing is, it works just fine if I leave `XMLParserDelegate` with the default internal visibility. Since `NSXMLParser` is defined outside of my module, presumably there should be no difference between `internal` and `private` in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: That still doesn't shock me. If internal didn't work for delegates, most code would break. But I usually find if I mark protocol conformance private, Swift gives me an error. I suspect that your nesting is getting in the way of the error (likely due to a bug in the compiler, though note that Martin is not seeing this issue).

Comment: While it is certainly true that most code would break if `internal` didn't work, that doesn't explain why it's reasonable for `private` not to work. This still feels like a bug to me. As for nesting, I provided an un-nested version of the code that still has the same problem in the original post.

Comment: In response to your edit, I don't dispute that you're correct about `private` hiding things at runtime: You _are_ correct, it would seem! The problem is that this behavior is _surprising_ and unlike how it works in Java, C#, et cetera. The class is _not_ hidden at the point where it is used, and hence it _should_ respond to the methods its declaration says it implements. It seems as if private classes cannot usefully implement any protocols right now, and that's certainly not desirable or expected.

Comment: Private classes can implement any non-ObjC protocol right now, and any ObjC protocol that doesn't have optional methods. The only conflict is with optional conformance (which is not available in Swift protocols). I'm not familiar with how Java and C# manage optional methods in protocols with private classes.

Comment: Ah, you are correct again! Unfortunately, most Objective-C protocols do have optional methods and hence it's _almost_ as if I can't implement any of the protocols I want to implement—at least not with private classes.

Comment: It certainly does create a surprising behavior given that there is no compiler warning (and it may be nontrivial to add one). The quietness of the error is certainly troubling, even if it were intended behavior. Too easy to get spooky action at a distance (you make something private, and suddenly thing stop working without errors).

Answer (score 0):

Similar bug already existed prior to XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052c), it was fixed in that version and now introduced again in XCode Version 6.3 (6D532l).

At that time (before 6.1) there was another bug where you had to manually change `NSXMLParserDelegate` signature for `func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String...` method by making some parameters implicitly unwrapped in order to fix `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` error.
Read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793940/parser-parse-in-swift-leads-to-exc-bad-access/25797967#25797967)

After you've done that, this method wasn't called if class using it was marked as private, so it had to be at least internal in order to work.

Apple fixed this method signature in 6.1 and then I was able to make parser class private ([see this](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML/commit/407e997a1ffc4fa41e6b8dd1b07f56a236989e4d#diff-79bea0ad5ca826e6cdbcdd9fe2ca6cb8R201)) which worked great until XCode 6.3 / Swift 1.2.

Now, I'm not sure it that's a bug or intended behaviour, so I think I'm gonna wait for the next official version to see what should I do with my [XML Parsing library](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML).

Btw, nothing is changed in Xcode 6.3 Beta 4.